# Command "apt-get-repository" doesn't work on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt

I'm trying to install Libreoffice 4.0 on Ubuntu 12.04. I try to begin with add the repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-0
```

I get this output:

```
sudo: apt-get-repository: command not found
```

Tested to run

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
```

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-software-properties is already the newest version.
software-properties-common is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: I see some inconsistency there: `add-apt-repository` vs `apt-get-repository`, was that a typo or did you really get a different error?

Comment: Try `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa`

Comment: Used 'apt-get-repository'. Love you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in the comments:
I see some inconsistency there: add-apt-repository vs apt-get-repository, was that a typo or did you really get a different error? – guntbert 3 hours ago
Try sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa – Mitch 3 hours ago

Adding it as an answer, so this can be ticked off as the correct answer, closing this.

(Added this answer as community karma as I had little to do with it ;) )